# Custom style for activity - OnStart doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, onstart

I am kind of newbie here. But would like to ask you guys for help.

so what my app is doing.
In activity#1 I have :

```
protected void onStart() where I run void run()
```

there's a loop that increases int i each second. Via handler it refreshes `textview`. Until game=false. No big deal.
Then I have a button that stops loop (by setting `game=false`) and starts new `activity#2` for result. At the moment I have two `returning values (0-back, 1-exit)`. When activity#2 returns 0 I set `game=true` and loop is running again. In case of 1 I finish activity1.

Issue:
I wanted to have trasparent window for `activity#2`. So I used `android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">.` Effect works well. The problem is that when I go back from act2 to act1 it doesn't start loop (it used to work when I didn't use style). Can someone explain me why it's happing and how can I solve it?

seems I've solved it. Just moved `run()` stuff into onResume.
what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

When you do something during when activity is restored, resumed or brought again back to the front override the onResume. If you have started the other activity with startActivityForResult(Intent,requesCode), when you go back to the previous activity should override the onActivityResult(int requestCode,resultCode, Intent) of that activity to execute lines of code base on the intent, requestCode or resultCode.

Dig more about android activity [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). :)